# FireFox and only FireFox behaves strange

Tags: jquery

i wrote hover animation in jQuery and it works great but does not work as expected in FireFox, could u look at this and tell me how this can happen

hover on the green field and the blue one should enter smoothly, but in FF animation is not smooth there is a jump

http://jsfiddle.net/mrNRx/

Comment: Looks fine to me in FF 14, except for the very first one which was a little jumpy.

Comment: This is a little jump I'm talking about, in my FF14 this little jump is all the time

Comment: Same here - looks fine. The first time an animation loads it often tends to jump. I've got around this in the past by pre-loading a class. All of this can now be done with CSS3 `transform` - e.g. see http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

Comment: css transform is cool but it has to work in IE8

Comment: With fadeIn callback seem better: `$(this).find('.apla').fadeIn("slow", function(){$(this).find('.more').animate({"bottom": "50px"},1000); });`

Comment: Alex u are great :], it works fine, thx meat

Comment: @gidzior ok, perfect ;-). I've post it like answer. Happy to be useful ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FadeIn() callback like this (your code simplified):

```
$(this).find('.apla').fadeIn("slow", function(){
     $(this).find('.more').animate({"bottom": "50px"},1000);
});

$(this).find('.apla').fadeOut("slow", function(){
     $(this).find('.more').animate({"bottom": "-40px"},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Mozilla's stupid -moz-box-shadow. Remove it with the following css code and it should fix the issue.

```
*{box-shadow:none!important;-moz-box-shadow:none!important;border-radius:0!important;-moz-border-radius:0!important}
```

Comment: I am afraid that this is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use jQuery hover intent plugin to use Over and Out functions. In firefox these events are not firing proerply. In chrome these functions fires properly and your readme link is working fine.